# Why can't redirect stderr into a file with exec?

Tags: bash, exec

I want to redirect stderr into a file `/tmp/mytest`:

```
exec 2> /tmp/mytest
```

Press enter after input `exec 2> /tmp/mytest`, the cursor remains there,why command `exec 2> /tmp/mytest` can't fulfill?

[image]

Comment: You haven't given `exec` a command to execute.

Comment: @DavidPostill `exec` without any command to execute is [perfectly fine](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why command `exec 2> /tmp/mytest` can't fulfill?

It can and it does. The prompt you're waiting for went to the redirected stderr, i.e. to `/tmp/mytest`. From now on whatever you type will be echoed to the file, not to the terminal. If you try to move the cursor then sequences responsible for cursor movement will also go to the file.

Blindly type `echo foo`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and see what happens.

<sup>(If there is no output, it means that most likely the command line was not empty before you typed `echo`. But now it probably is. Repeat.)</sup>

The shell operates normally and you can cast commands. You cannot see what has been redirected.

If you use `exec 2> /tmp/mytest` in a script then its ability to "hijack" the prompt won't matter because shells interpreting scripts don't print prompts like interactive shells do. Exceptions:

- if you source the script, `exec 2> /tmp/mytest` in it *will* affect the shell from which you source;
- commands in scripts can print their own prompts, they can use stderr for this.

---

The question is about Bash. Many other shells behave like Bash.

It's worth noting Zsh doesn't use stderr to print the prompt. In Zsh `exec 2> /tmp/mytest` does not redirect the prompt. I guess this is the behavior you expected.